# Dynamically add a button - must be placed inside form tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am dynamically creating a button using C#. but i get an error when it get executed;

```
Control 'butidd' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.
```

the code

```
                Button but = new Button();
                but.ID = "butidd";
                but.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                but.Text = "test";
                but.Click += new EventHandler(but_click);
                this.Controls.Add(but);
```

click event:

```
void but_click(object sender, EventArgs e){}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `but = "butidd";` and `but = "test;`? You can't set an object of type `Button` to match a `string`. Also afaik, you can't edit an object of type `Button` to have custom attributes, create a subclass instead.

Comment: @TiesonT. It's obviously the form where hiws button is placed into.

Comment: @Mahi Obviously not, hence the error.

Answer (score 3):

As the error clearly states, you need to add the control somewhere inside a `<form runat="server">`; not directly in the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the control dynamically... Better create a panel in form design view and add the control dynamically to that panel...

If you create a panel on design view then it lays under the form tag...It is easiest one.... it avoids this type of confusions and errors...

try this link for reference... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx